# Android Tablet Only app can be downloaded on Phablets

Tags: android, screen, android-manifest

I've initially developped an android tablet-only app by adding the following declaration in the app manifest as described in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps):

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

The problem is that my app was release quite a long time ago and now, we have some customer who are installing them on "Phablets" such as *Galaxy Note 4* or *Nexus 6* which have incredible (and incredibly stupid?) resolutions for phone: 1440x2560, 16:9 aspect ratio, etc.

So i hope we all agree that "Phablet" is not a real commercial product segmentation right? (or does we have to see it as a tablet with a sim card entry, making the boundaries really unclear?).

How can i force the Phablets to be considered as Phone and be unable to download my app?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can black-list specific phones in the Google Play Console if you are specifically looking to remove phones close to tablets that you know of.  However, there is no black and white way to find out if something is a phone or a tablet, as you have already pointed out that the lines are blurred.

Comment: Stupid question maybe... but why would you want to do that? If the application works reasonably on a phablet, why limit the amount of people willing to use it?

Comment: @Wildcopper, your question is not stupid at all.  I just have to convince the Stakeholders that this is a good working way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no technical answer to this issue.
We have convinced the business that Phablet are a "kind of" tablets.